# Find RapidJSON value's parent

Tags: rapidjson

Given a Value in a RapidJSON document, is it possible to easily find that Value's parent?

Specifically, we're using Pointer to find a value, but we then want to move back up one level to find that value's parent.

I was hoping there would be an easily available GetParent() or even a Pointer statement that would move me up one level, but so far I haven't found it.

All I've come up with is to then iterate through the entire tree, checking child items until I find it.  I haven't tried to do that yet, but presumably it's possible (but wildly inefficient).

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is dead simple and I'd missed it in reading the JSON Pointer docs.  To move up one level from a particular point:

```
1
```

So to move up one level and then descend into a branch named "Foods":

```
1/Foods
```

To move up two levels and then descend into a branch named "Simple":

```
2/Simple
```

Comment: Turns out the reason I had such trouble making this work was...  RapidJson doesn't seem to support relative pointers.